# Node Async Waterfall with generic callback handler

Tags: node.js, async.js

I have inherited an application which relies entirely on async.waterfall for one of its controllers. I don't want to re-write the whole thing, but in fixing a couple items want to convert the callback param into a more generic handler.

Right now an example function looks like the below (same pattern exists for like a dozen more functions)

```
function create(data, callbackParent) {
  async.waterfall(
    [
      function(callback) {
        if (!interface) {
          return init(callback);
        } else {
          return callback(null);
        }
      },
      function(callback) {
        return interface.create(data, callback);
      }
    ],
    (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        const codeIndex = error.indexOf('statusCode=') + 'statusCode='.length;
        const errorStatusCode = error.slice(codeIndex, codeIndex + 3);
        if(errorStatusCode == 401) {
          reconnect(callbackParent);
        }
        else {
          return callbackParent(error);
        }
      }
      return callbackParent(null, result);
    }
  );
}
```

No problem and works great; however, notice the callback there. I am trying to move that into some generic function handleResponse(error, result) for example:

```
function create(data, callbackParent) {
  async.waterfall(
    [
      function(callback) {
        if (!interface) {
          return init(callback);
        } else {
          return callback(null);
        }
      },
      function(callback) {
        return interface.create(data, callback);
      }
    ],
    (error, result) => handleResponse
  );
}
```

I've tried various combos of syntax like the above but either everything blows up, or I lose context to my callbackParent.

1. How can I construct the callback for an async.waterfall array to be a separate and generic handler?

Comment: Instead of `(error, result) => handleResponse`, leave just `handleResponse`.

Comment: @alexmac That fixed it, if you want to post it as an answer here I'll accept it